# How to resolve "Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1"?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Flutter Version: *2.6.0-12.0.pre.381*

Dart Version: *2.15.0*

Gradle version : *distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip*

In pubspec.yaml, I have these packages:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  splashscreen: ^1.2.0
  bottom_navy_bar:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  image_picker: ^0.8.0+4
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.7
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  share: ^2.0.4
  flutter_barcode_scanner: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.0
  dropdown_search: ^1.0.0
  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer:
  ndialog: ^4.1.0
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.0.4
  http: ^0.13.3
  dio: ^4.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.3
  downloads_path_provider_28: ^0.1.2
  permission_handler: ^8.1.4+2
  open_file: ^3.2.1
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.0.0
```

Same packages are working in another project.
Any suggestions on how to fix the problem. I think it is due to some error in build.graddle.

I have changed minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in build.gradle as follows:

```
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
```

It is showing error while running the project:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM M205F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\downloads_path_provider_28-0.1.2\android\src\main\java\it\nplace\downloadspathprovider\DownloadsPathProviderPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.8.4+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionManager.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                                                            ^
  symbol:   variable R
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionManager.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
                status = Environment.isExternalStorageManager()
                                    ^
  symbol:   method isExternalStorageManager()
  location: class Environment
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionManager.java:254: error: cannot find symbol
                    if (permission == PermissionConstants.PERMISSION_GROUP_MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                                                                                          ^
  symbol:   variable R
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionManager.java:268: error: cannot find symbol
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R && permission == PermissionConstants.PERMISSION_GROUP_MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {
                                                                   ^
  symbol:   variable R
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionManager.java:270: error: cannot find symbol
                        Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION,
                                ^
  symbol:   variable ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION
  location: class Settings
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionManager.java:321: error: cannot find symbol
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable S
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionManager.java:349: error: cannot find symbol
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                                                               ^
  symbol:   variable R
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionManager.java:380: error: cannot find symbol
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                                                                   ^
  symbol:   variable R
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionManager.java:384: error: cannot find symbol
                    return Environment.isExternalStorageManager()
                                      ^
  symbol:   method isExternalStorageManager()
  location: class Environment
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
            case Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                                    ^
  symbol:   variable MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  location: class permission
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
            case Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN:
                                    ^
  symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_SCAN
  location: class permission
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
            case Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE:
                                    ^
  symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE
  location: class permission
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
            case Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT:
                                    ^
  symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
  location: class permission
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:235: error: cannot find symbol
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R && hasPermissionInManifest(context, permissionNames, Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ))
                                                                ^
  symbol:   variable R
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:235: error: cannot find symbol
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R && hasPermissionInManifest(context, permissionNames, Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ))
                                                                                          ^
  symbol:   variable MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  location: class permission
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:236: error: cannot find symbol
                    permissionNames.add(Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  location: class permission
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:259: error: cannot find symbol
                String result = determineBluetoothPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_SCAN
  location: class permission
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:270: error: cannot find symbol
                String result = determineBluetoothPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE);
                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE
  location: class permission
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:281: error: cannot find symbol
                String result = determineBluetoothPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
  location: class permission
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:370: error: cannot find symbol
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S && hasPermissionInManifest(context, null, permission )) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable S
  location: class VERSION_CODES
20 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':permission_handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 44s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 10):

This is happing due to `compileSdkVersion`. Head over to `android/app/build.gradle` and change `complieSdkVersion` to 31.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    ...
}
```

In `pubspec.yaml` file :-

```
dependencies:
  permission_handler: ^8.2.5
```

The error must be happening in versions 8.2.0 and onwards. If you still encounter some error then install a version less 8.2.0.

Comment: In my case I didn't install permission handler, but it was a dependency of one of the packages I installed (form_builder_file_picker)

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue and this is how i solved it:

First i removed permission_handler from my yaml file.

Then did a flutter clean.
[image: Clean Cache]

In pubspec.yaml : I changed the version of the **permission_handler** plugin from 8.2.6 to:

```
permission_handler: ^8.2.0
```

[image: permission_handler]

Then In android/app/build.grale file:changed compile sdk version to 31.

Comment: Changing compile SDK to version 31 is enough. The alternative solution is reverting permission_handler to 8.2.0, not both.

Comment: The error continued to persist on my end even after changing to 31

Answer (score 1):

I think that  `Build.VERSION_CODES.R` is API Level 30 , so setting [compileSdkVersion](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#sdk-constraints) to 30 should fix the issue .

Comment: It didn't work. It is showing same error again.

Comment: The problem was happening because of   permission_handler: ^8.1.4+2   package. I removed the package and ran the project it is working now. Only I have to add another package  please suggest alternate package.

Answer (score 1):

I changed  permission_handler: ^8.1.4+2  with  permission_handler: 6.0.0  in pubspec.yaml   .Now project is working fine. Thanks for your assistance.